# How write regular expression to only remove token if there is no charect in it

Tags: java, regex

I have some strings like "My room number is 564IEE in 3456 George St." and I only want to remove 3456 from the string.But, the follwoing regular expression remove 564 from 564IEE.

```
intputString.replaceAll("(\\d+[,. -]?\\d+)|\\d+", "");
```

Could You please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for this example this will work:

```
intputString = intputString.replaceAll("\\b\\d+\\b", "");
```

i.e. match any number with word boundary on either side.

Comment: what about a regural expression that string does not remove "657@" .

Comment: Sorry didn't get. What is input and what is expected output?

Comment: The input  and output are "657@"

Comment: Then you can use: `intputString = intputString.replaceAll("\\b\\d+(?:@|\\b)", "");`